# Wrapping CupertinoTextField placeholder text

Tags: flutter, flutter-cupertino

I'm trying to get the placeholder text in a `CupertinoTextField` to wrap to the next line, rather than being cut off with an ellipsis.

When I set `maxLines` to a value (e.g. 5), the placeholder text wraps. However, I want the TextField to expand with the user's input, so I need to set `maxLines` to null.

```
    return CupertinoTextField(
      controller: _textController,
      autofocus: true,
      placeholder:
          "This is a very long placeholder text that should wrap to the next line.",
      maxLines: null,
    );
```

Is there a workaround to get the placeholder text to wrap?

Comment: How did you go with this, was there a solution?

Comment: I ended up finding the line in Flutter's implementation of CupertinoTextField where overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis is set. Removing that overflow line caused the text to wrap as desired.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to set `minLines: 2`, and set `maxLines: (greater than 2)` make sure `expands` is set to false or excluded.